# How to pass BOOL variable as parameter in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

This might be a stupid question, but in my app there will be a need to pass a bool variable to a method.

Let's say I have 10 `BOOL` variables declared as `b1,b2.....b10`.

I can send `BOOL` value as a parameter by simply with the following code:

```
[self sendBoolValue:YES];      

- (void)sendBoolValue:(BOOL)value 
{
    b1 = value;
    // now b1 will be YES.
}
```

Now what I need is something which does this:

```
[self sendBoolVariable:b1];  // I tried sending &b1, but it didnt work out. 

- (void)sendBoolVariable:(BOOL)value
{
    value = YES; // trying to set b1 to YES.
    // b1 is still NO.
}
```

I couldnt get to send the `BOOL` variable. IS this even possible ?

**Why I am doing this?:**

I have a UIView which has 9 subviews(I call these as tiles) in a 3x3 grid layout.

I have two `BOOL` values `startTile` and `endTile`. I need to set these values based on the touch!!!

I am using `touches-Began/Moved/Ended` to detect touches on these views

When the touches started, I need to calculate if the touch is in the tile1 or tile2.....

So the actual code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
// calculate touch point and based on it set the bool value
    [self sendBoolVariable:startTile];
  //startTile is selected, so change its color
  // lock other tiles    

}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

  //if touches came to tile 2 region
  [self sendBoolVariable:b2];   //b2 is BOOL variable for tile2 



}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self sendBoolVariable:endTile]; 

    //end tile is selcted too
     //at this point both start tile and tile are selected
     //now do the animation for the start tile and end tile
     //other tiles are still in locked state

}
```

As you can see, I need to call same method but need to send three different bool variables!!!!

Comment: Why are you trying to use s method to simply set a BOOL variable to YES or NO?

Comment: there is a case where I frequently modify the bool values from b1 to b10. So I wrote a method that perform some changes based on the b1...b10 values. It contains a switch statemnt which has 10 cases. Each cases perform work relate to the touch CGPOINT!!!! I need to call the same method at different points with different variables!!!

Comment: so instead of having multiple methods, I put one method, and I want to pass variables to that method

Comment: You should update your question with more relevant code and a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I will do for sure . It's 4!! I am rushing now to catch the transit to go home!!! Will do that once I get to home!!!

Comment: I did got a chance to conncet my hotspot!!!! I updated the question @rmaddy :)

Comment: I am doin that because, I need to call the same method and all the code in that  method doesnt change except that only code related to bool variables will be changed!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you want but you can do:

```
[self sendBoolVariable:&b1];

- (void)sendBoolVariable:(BOOL *)value {
    *value = YES; //b1 is now YES        
}
```

Comment: @Mr.T This was the point of my original comment below the question. Why do you need a method for this? This code can be replaced with `b1 = YES;`.

Comment: you are right maddy, the code can be replaced with b1=YES!!! But at some point, I need to have b2=YES, ad at some point I need to have b3=YES, and at some point I need to have b4=YES!!!!! So I need to send the variable to this method and make it YES!! The other lines of code should remain same!!!! :) @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

Following your clarifications, how about:

```
BOOL a = YES;
a = [self modifyBoolValueBasedOnItself:a]; // the method takes the BOOL as a parameter and returns the modified value
```

An BOOL is just a a signed char.
If you're trying to change the value of a property, try self.variable = YES or _variable = YES

Also kudos to [barry wark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140/barry-wark) for the following:

From the definition in objc.h:

```
typedef signed char     BOOL; 
// BOOL is explicitly signed so @encode(BOOL) == "c" rather than "C" 
// even if -funsigned-char is used.
#define OBJC_BOOL_DEFINED
#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the BOOL b1 to the method:

```
[self sendBoolVariable:b1];
```

"value" has a scope limited to the method. So when you set value=YES:

```
-(void)sendBoolVariable:(BOOL) value{
         value=YES;
```

you are not changing the value of the broader scope ivar "b1".